# Display each department’s number and name and the number of employees employed in each department

Tags: sql

This is what I tried and cant get it to work

```
SELECT d.deptno,d.dname
COUNT('e.empno') "number of employees"
FROM dept,emp
WHERE d.deptno = e.deptno
GROUP BY d.deptno,d.dname
```

any help is much appreciated thanks

Comment: This is missing a comma before count

Comment: You probably don't need quotes around column name.

Comment: Which variation of SQL are you using? And what happened when you tried running the above? If you got an error message, post that. If you got an unexpected result, describe it.

Comment: You are missing either a `,` or `AS`.

Answer (score 1):

In sql-server it'll be like

```
SELECT d.deptno,d.dname,
COUNT(e.empno) as number_of_employees
FROM dept d,emp e
WHERE d.deptno = e.deptno
GROUP BY d.deptno,d.dname


the error occurs when you undefined the instance of the table used
```

just in case more optimized will be

> SELECT d.deptno,d.dname,
>       COUNT(e.empno) as number_of_employees
>       FROM dept d join emp e
>       on d.deptno = e.deptno
>       GROUP BY d.deptno,d.dname

Comment: If anyone uses Microsoft Dynamics CRM, I created a variation on this to show the number of contacts per account with this query:  SELECT a.AccountId,a.Name,
COUNT(c.ParentCustomerId) as number_of_contacts
FROM accountbase a,contactbase c
WHERE a.accountid = c.ParentCustomerId
GROUP BY a.accountid,a.Name

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have some syntax errors:

1. The COUNT(Something) is something to select, so it should be separated with a comma after "d.dname". Also, like Guillaume pointed out, it is a column and not a string, so no quotes are needed:
   SELECT d.deptno, d.dname, COUNT(e.empno)
2. You use aliases like "d" and "e", but you did not define them.  You would do this like:
   "FROM departments d"
3. the join should be written as follows:
   "INNER JOIN employees e ON e.deptno = d.deptno
   (This is technically not a syntax error, but I advice to use inner join explicitly)
4. The comments should be prefixed with '--'

P.S. Assuming T-SQL / MS SQL Server here.

Comment: Your third point is *not* a syntax error. It is fine to do a cross join, then filtering in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Agreed, let me edit. But you think that the query optimizer will automatically make that an inner join? It might, but I would always write joins explicitly. Much more readable, especially if you have multiple joins. Right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you might be using Oracle, in which case the fix is fairly simple:

```
SELECT d.deptno, d.dname, count(e.empno) "number of employees"
FROM dept d, emp e
WHERE d.deptno = e.deptno
GROUP BY d.deptno, d.dname
```

You need to explicitly tell the DB what the aliases are referring to. The error message likely mentioned an invalid/missing identifier 'd', meaning that it didn't know what that was.

Comment: Doesn't that FROM statement do a cartesian product, rather than an inner join?

Comment: I don't think so, I think it's implemented a little differently in Oracle, because they weren't playing well with the standard. AFAIK this performs better than using 'inner join', because that was implemented as an afterthought.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT d.department_id, 
       d.department_name, 
       COUNT(e.employee_id) as number_of_employees
FROM departments d 
JOIN employees e 
    on d.department_id = e.department_id 
GROUP BY d.department_id, d.department_name;
```